# Wrong encoding in Taxonomies extra for MODX Revo

Tags: utf-8, modx, modx-revolution

Everything in manager page displays correctly, but Taxonomies tab. [Link to Taxonomies extra.](https://modx.com/extras/package/taxonomies)

modx_charset is set to UTF-8 in system settings, I also added "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" line in .htaccess. Database is also in UTF-8.
What can cause this? 
Or maybe someone can tell me what I can use instead of this extra.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an encoding problem. Check charset of tables added by this extras - `page_terms`.